# Unable to load android view when trying to load an app from background to foreground

Tags: android

I am new to android. I am developing an android app which is location based (capturing users location coordinates). In my app, I have a timer which runs a particular method to flush my location coordinates from sqlite database to server (through a web service call).

Please find my following code which has a timer onCreate view:

```
Timer itsLocationTimer;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
myLocationTimer();
}

private void myLocationTimer()
{
long flushDuration = 10000;
try 
{
    itsLocationTimer = new Timer();
    itsLocationTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() 
    {           
    @Override
        public void run() {
         TimerMethod();
    }
     }, 0, flushDuration);
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

private void TimerMethod()
{
     sendLocationCoordinatesToServer();
}
```

When I run my app in foreground mode, I have no issues in location triggering or sending them to server (using my timer).

Now I switched my app to background mode and kept it running for few minutes.

On switching my app from background to foreground, I was unable to load my view. My app crashed.

It displayed the following message in logcat:

```
09-28 18:12:51.476: D/dalvikvm(7394): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 70K, 48% free 2847K/5379K, external 499K/517K, paused 136ms
09-28 18:12:51.539: D/AndroidRuntime(7394): Shutting down VM
09-28 18:12:51.539: W/dalvikvm(7394): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40018578)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.org.myApp/com.org.myApp.view.HomeView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at com.org.myApp.view.cub.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:90)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
09-28 18:12:51.554: E/AndroidRuntime(7394):     ... 11 more
```

Can any one please suggest me where the issue is? Why my app is crashed when switching it from background to foreground.

Any suggestions please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

check the HomeView.java file at 90 line you got the nullpointerexception there. May be layout was not set in onCreate() or layout which have set that layout not contain this control that's why you getting the npe

```
com.org.myApp.view.cub.HomeView.onCreate(HomeView.java:90)
```

Comment: Thank you for the immediate reply. My HomeView has the following line 'setContentView(R.layout.home_view) in onCreate()'. This layout loads was loaded successfully when its running in foreground. But when I switch my app from foreground to background and change it back to foreground, this exception was thrown. Can you please suggest me  where the issue is.. whether any properties needed for an app to load in background and switch them back to foreground successfully? Thank you again.

Comment: And also at the line number 90, I am calling a singleton class:  MyApp.getConfigJson().toString() to load some particular values.